# FFT with Java unexpected results

Tags: java

I'm am trying to implement a FFT algorithm in Java. I look at a c++ code and translated everything, however I don't get expected result.

This is the code describing FFT:

```java
 static void fft(Complex[] x)
 {

    int N = x.length;
    if (N <= 1) return;

    // divide

    Complex[] even;
    Complex[] odd;

    odd = new Complex[(int) N/2];
    even = new Complex[N - odd.length]; 

    int a = 0; 
    int b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            even[a] = x[i];
            a++;
        } else {
            odd[b] = x[i];
            b++;
        }  
    }

    // conquer
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (int k = 0; k < N/2; ++k) {
        double newAngl = -2 * (Math.PI) * k / N;
        Complex t =  ((Complex) ComplexUtils.polar2Complex(1.0, newAngl)).multiply(odd[k]);
        x[k] = even[k].add(t);
        x[k+N/2] = even[k].subtract(t);
    }
}
```

And if I generate a complex array using:

```
Complex[] test = new Complex[700];
for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    test[i] = new Complex(3 * Math.cos(5 * Math.PI * i), 0);
}
```

Then doing fft(test) and then plotting test[i].abs() over (i) index, I get this graph (I plot half of the data values as they are mirrored in N/2)

[image]

I don't really understand this. Im using a simple cosine function with period of 5 * pi. Shouldn't I get **1** peak in the graph instead of many different as it is just clean data with no noise. When doing the same thing in MatLab I get this graph:

[image]

The code is:

```
i= [0:700];
X = 3*sin(5*pi*i);
fftmat = fft(X)
pfftmat = abs(fftmat);
plot(pfftmat);
```

Here we get many peaks aswell (I know I have plotted all the data entries, but when you look at from 0 to 350, there are many peaks). Can somebody tell me of what I got wrong? Or doesn't fft work with "perfect" data?

Comment: your Java gives the same results as your matlab implementation, except the matlab implementation runs to 4pi instead of pi. So either both are right or both are wrong.

Comment: The period of your test signal is 2/5 of your sampling rate, I.e. it is too high frequency to be sampled at your sampling rate due to the nyquist limit. You need a signal whose frequency is less than half of your sampling rate, I.e. the multiplier of the index in your cosine function should be less than pi.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me! I just divided the i by a sample rate, and it gave me peaks as expected! (sadly i can't mark your comment as an answer but i hope other people see this)